# Get logged in userId from a 'me' relative id in /users/me spring boot api

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

We have a bunch of secured web services (using spring security) defined like this:

```
@GetMapping("/users/{userId}")
public User getUserInfo(@PathVariable String userId) {
...
@GetMapping("/users/{userId}/addresses")
public User getUserInfo(@PathVariable String userId) {
```

If I want to get the logged in user, I can add the `Principal principal` or `HttpServletRequest request` to the method and spring will support the data for the logged in user, or also I can use `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`.

So far so good, if we want to get the logged in user for the api `/users/1234` we have no problem. However we got a requirement to support a relative userId value being `me` where the api would be `/users/me`.

We could resolve this by adding in each api just an `if` statement and replacing the userId `me` with the real logged in userId. We don't like this implementation since we have a boilerplate code in 20 apis. So, another solution we tried was by just adding an aspect to replace the `me` by the real userId but I don't like using reflection for solving this problem.

So, i was wondering if there is a "spring boot" way of doing this? I haven't found any feature supporting this behavior.

Comment: I would recommend to implement it as a new method, because in most cases you can't do the same operations on your own and a different user. For exmaple you can change your own user, but not change other users.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to change that URL. If statement is ver explicit too though. There are interceptors as well you could use but I don't see them as being much different to using aspects, pretty evil stuff. But if you do use aspects I would suggest that you have an annotation such as `@Me` which you could annotated method inputs such as `userId` with, which would replace them with the id of the principal if the parameter is equal to me.